# magento 2:How i add header.phtml file in default.xml page

Tags: magento2

I can create a header.phtml file and call in default.xml
this is my code

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml"/>
```

this is my code 
and header position is mytheme/magento_theme/template/html/header.phtml

Comment: folder should be like this `Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

Comment: `phtml` file must be in `templates` folder.

Comment: yes my file path is same here but header is not come

Comment: share your full XML code

Comment: kunj  sir your skype in on

Comment: yes, you can get from here :  https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/66125/kunj?tab=profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your `template` folder name as `templates` so it should be like this: `Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can write this block inside this:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

And check once again the paths.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be like this:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
```

If you want to add an additional one:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header1.phtml
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header1.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: yes, I change name header.phtml to header1.phtml but header does not come

Comment: @shohel hussain no, you haven't to change it, this is the natife Magento header one, you can override it in your theme, or you can add a new one